# Angular 2 horizontal stacked chart

Tags: angular, charts

I need to implement a chart that looks like the following. Each bar represents a percentage of the total. For example the purple bar is about 40%, the darkest blue is about 10%, the green is about 8%, etc. I googled around, but I couldn't find anything that does exactly that, the close I found was [this](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_horizontal_mekko), but I'm not sure if it'll do the trick.

Has anybody here done something like that? It's starting to look like it's gonna have to be custom implementation, which I'm trying to stay away from.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it need to be _specific_ Angular? Or do you want to only set the width (and values) with Angular?

Comment: Hmm not sure I understand the question. I'm working on an Angular2 project, so I would think it HAS to be Angulars, therein lies the part I don't understand =P. Can it NOT be Angular2 in some way?

Comment: You could just build this with only CSS (flexbox) and populate the width with Angular values.

Comment: @Roy Ok, that's interesting, I've never heard of flexbox before, I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple setup of what you want to achieve. It doesn't use any chart library, only Angular 4.2 and flexbox (CSS).

Put the values of the chart in an array (`this.items` in *app.ts*):

```js
    export class App {
      constructor() {
        this.items = [6, 11, 17, 21, 45];
      }
    }
```

These are just some sample values, together they are 100(%).

Populate them in the HTML (*app.component.html*) and set the width of a bar as percentage (see `[style.width]="item + '%'"`), using the values from *app.ts*. The index is not particularly needed, but it can be handy when you want to see which chart part is rendered.

```js
<ul class="valuechart">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [style.width]="item + '%'">
    {{i}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Give the `<ul>` some flexbox properties (read more about CSS flexbox [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)) to stretch the bar horizontally and let it fill out.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

The rest of the styling is just some markup to show it a bit nice.

[image: Full width bar chart with CSS flexbox and Angular]

Check out [**the demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ksNqt4uSR35TjDqn0b8T?p=preview) I put together.

Comment: Very awesome! Exactly what I needed, I owe you a beer! Thanks Roy!